# Deploying MoonMail resoruces AwsMarketplaceNotificationsQueuePolicy

Tags: aws-cloudformation, moonmail

I'm getting an invalid parameter error on AwsMarketplaceNotificationsQueuePolicy while creating the stack.

Has anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: Not yet, can you add more details to what exactly you did and the full error?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. In my case, the reason was a missing variable - `awsMarketplaceUserArn` in the `_meta/variables/s-variables-<stage>-<region>.json` file.